# Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'S.No' in 'order clause'

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting the below error while using the following query using "ORDER BY" Clause, S.No (int type) does exist in the table, not sure why am hitting this error? Any ideas how to fix it?

```
SELECT gerrit_id
FROM gerrits.gerrit_table
WHERE (((SU_version>='00.00.0001')&&(SU_version<='00.00.0006'))
    AND PL='LA.HB.1.1.1'
    AND component='SU_CNSS_BT_FM_LA.HB.1.1.1') 
ORDER BY S.No
```

Error:-

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'S.No' in 'order clause'
```

Table schema

```
Field   Type    Null    Key Default Extra
S.No    int(11) NO  PRI NULL    auto_increment
gerrit_id   varchar(45) NO  PRI NULL    
SI  varchar(45) NO  PRI NULL    
component   varchar(45) NO  PRI NULL    
gerrit_owner    varchar(45) NO  PRI NULL    
release_bit int(11) NO  PRI NULL    
picked_bit  int(11) NO  PRI NULL
```

Comment: Please copy in your table schema so that we can see the columns that you have available.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - yes I do have a column name with type int(11) set to auto increment

Comment: @DanielWaghorn - How do I copy the table schema here?

Comment: @user2125827 if you are using phpmyadmin then go to "structure" in your table and take a screenshot, if not just run a query `DESCRIBE your_table;`

Comment: @user2125827 easiest thing to do I'd say is as mentioned by @Pholochtairze do `DESCRIBE your_table;` and edit your original post pasting it in as code.

Comment: @DanielWaghorn - Updated the original post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm surprised that the DBMS has accepted the column name `S.No` although try this:

```
SELECT gerrit_id
FROM gerrits.gerrit_table
WHERE (((SU_version>='00.00.0001')&&(SU_version<='00.00.0006'))
    AND PL='LA.HB.1.1.1'
    AND component='SU_CNSS_BT_FM_LA.HB.1.1.1') 
ORDER BY `S.No`
```

Comment: what is the issue with S.No, why do you think DBMS should not accept this?

Comment: It's just unusual since MySQL would normally interpret that dot as a prompt to access a field in another table or via an alias, although if it's accepted it and it works fine for you then no harm.

Comment: I think DBMS thinks he will have problems differentiating this and an alias. For instance you have a table `table AS S` then if `table` has a column `No`you would also call it `S.No`. Edit : better said by @DanielWaghorn.

Comment: According to [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html): `Database and table names cannot contain “/”, “\”, “.”, or characters that are not permitted in file names`